# How to perform a dump from a Python script in Rethinkdb

Tags: python, rethinkdb

As described in https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/backup/, when using the command line, it is possible to create a backup of a Rethinkdatabase using the command

`rethinkdb dump`

I'm interested in doing something similar from within a Python script, not from the command line. How can this be achieved?

As an example, consider the following code from the ten-minute introduction to RethinkDB:

```
import rethinkdb as r
r.connect("localhost", 28015).repl()
r.db("test").table_drop("authors").run()        # This line is included in case the script has already been run before
r.db("test").table_create("authors").run()

r.table("authors").insert([
    { "name": "William Adama", "tv_show": "Battlestar Galactica",
      "posts": [
        {"title": "Decommissioning speech", "content": "The Cylon War is long over..."},
        {"title": "We are at war", "content": "Moments ago, this ship received..."},
        {"title": "The new Earth", "content": "The discoveries of the past few days..."}
      ]
    },
    { "name": "Laura Roslin", "tv_show": "Battlestar Galactica",
      "posts": [
        {"title": "The oath of office", "content": "I, Laura Roslin, ..."},
        {"title": "They look like us", "content": "The Cylons have the ability..."}
      ]
    },
    { "name": "Jean-Luc Picard", "tv_show": "Star Trek TNG",
      "posts": [
        {"title": "Civil rights", "content": "There are some words I've known since..."}
      ]
    }
]).run()

cursor = r.table("authors").run()
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

Running this script produces the following standard output:

```
{u'tv_show': u'Battlestar Galactica', u'posts': [{u'content': u'The Cylon War is long over...', u'title': u'Decommissioning speech'}, {u'content': u'Moments ago, this ship received...', u'title': u'We are at war'}, {u'content': u'The discoveries of the past few days...', u'title': u'The new Earth'}], u'id': u'cc5f79c4-230b-4f6d-a642-db124c2ca9ad', u'name': u'William Adama'}
{u'tv_show': u'Star Trek TNG', u'posts': [{u'content': u"There are some words I've known since...", u'title': u'Civil rights'}], u'id': u'dd8b9963-34af-429d-8993-1c6be007367d', u'name': u'Jean-Luc Picard'}
{u'tv_show': u'Battlestar Galactica', u'posts': [{u'content': u'I, Laura Roslin, ...', u'title': u'The oath of office'}, {u'content': u'The Cylons have the ability...', u'title': u'They look like us'}], u'id': u'f3641355-282d-4fd6-ada6-1459246c054f', u'name': u'Laura Roslin'}
```

I'd like to write this data to a JSON file from within the Python script.

Comment: I don't have a solution for your question, but you might want to rethink using RethinkDB, because the company has shut down. https://rethinkdb.com/blog/rethinkdb-shutdown/

Comment: That 'standard output' looks a lot like JSON to my (admittedly inexperienced) eyes. Are you asking how to write a JSON file with Python?

Comment: [Rad Lexus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/rad-lexus), yes, I'd like to periodically write 'old' contents of the database to a JSON file with Python. I thought that RethinkDB's `dump` feature could be employed from within Python, but other methods would be good as well.